# What's the convention for when a user logs in with Google OAuth using the same Gmail that was already used to create an account in a traditional way?

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, google-authentication

I'm new to Google OAuth so I'm not too familiar with the OAuth authentication convention. Let's say a user creates an account with `some@gmail.com` in a traditional way (not related to Google authentication). Let's call this account A. When the same user logs in using Google OAuth that uses the same email address `some@gmail.com`, should the user be logged into the same account A? Meaning, the user would be able to see the same things within his profile including things like his purchase history, notification settings, etc.

If so, what's the convention for merging the user information? Logging in with Google provides its own `given_name`, `family_name`, and `photoUrl`. And creating an account traditionally with email and password would have it's own registration of name and the profile picture.

If not, what do you use as the UID being that email is usually a common field used as UID. You could create a separate user database, one for a traditional login and one for Google OAuth, but this seems extremely ineffective, knowing that you'd have to search both database each time when, say,  a posting is created to be related.

Or do you simply reject as duplicate when a user attempts to create or log in when the same email address already exists?

Comment: All built-in providers are considered equal in Firebase Authentication. What do you mean with "a traditional way" of creating an account here?

Comment: You're right. I've been told to separate the concept of user identity and user account and allow multiple identities to link to a single user account. A traditional way is simply signing up without using any OAuth methods like Google, Facebook, Twitter.

Comment: Instead of saying what traditional isn't, can you say what it **is**? As you might have noticed I answered with an example, but you're the only one who can say for certain what you mean by "traditional" here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow the user to sign in with multiple providers, you:

1. Enable the [one account per email address](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/authentication/providers) setting in the Firebase dashboard.
2. Get the user to sign in with one provider, say email+password.
3. Get the user to sign in with the Google provider, but instead of signing them in with the credentials, [link the Google provider account with the existing email+password account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking#link-federated-auth-provider-credentials-to-a-user-account).

Now the user can sign in with either email+password or Google and their account and UID in Firebase will be the same.

Comment: Thank you for this. Firebase is definitely one of the ways I'm considering. What about when you're using Postgres and Node.js. What kind of structure would you recommend for the same 'one identity' paradigm? I can think of having a parent database for multiple logins.